# iFrames: Change the root URL hit by relative URL src's

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have an iFrame on my webpage that is from the *same origin* as its parent page. I'm loading page into there that has a bunch of `img`, `script`, `link`, etc. tags in it that all have *relative* `src`s such as `src="/imgs/img.jpeg"` as opposed to `src="http://mywebsite.com/imgs/img.jpeg"`.

What I want is for all of those resources to go to another server. So instead of hitting `http://mywebsite.com/imgs/img.jpeg` I want them to hit `http://yahoo.com/imgs/img.jpeg` or other website.

Is there a way to change the "base URL" or whatever of the iFrame so that all the relative `src`s will hit another website and get those resources, using javascript?

Are there some cross-origin policies this would violate? Definite answers please, no speculation...

And is there a better way than to brute-force change all the `src`s in the DOM and hack it all up...

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of HTML5.  Just set a BASE tag in your HEAD section.  In your example it would be:

```
<base href="http://yahoo.com/">
```

This will set the base for all relative URLs.